# sort alphabet list blogspot

Tags: javascript, html, blogspot

I have this script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function getposttitle(json) {

// Get total posts
var totalposts = json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t;

  for (var i = 0; i < totalposts; i++)
  {
    var posturl;  
    // Get rel=alternate for truly post url
    for (var j=0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++)
    {
      if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate')
      {
        break;
      }
    }

    var poststitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
    document.write('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+poststitle+'<br/>');

  }
    }    
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://BLOGURL.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/BLOGLABEL?alt=json-in-script&max-results=10000&callback=getposttitle"></script>
```

Now what should i change to sort it as an alphabet list?

And any idea to remove the **&max-results=10000** because if i remove it, only 25 results appear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the API:
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol

There are two parameters that are relevant to your question:

> max-results: The maximum number of entries to return.
>
> orderby: The order in which to return entries, such as lastmodified (the default), starttime, or updated.

Where you have this:

```
src="http://BLOGURL.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/BLOGLABEL?alt=json-in-script&max-results=10000&callback=getposttitle">
```

Change it to this:

```
src="http://BLOGURL.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/BLOGLABEL?alt=json-in-script&max-results=10000&orderby=title&callback=getposttitle">
```

Here I chose the title field as the field to order by rather than the default field (lastmodified). You can set max-results to a smaller number, for example 100, to get fewer results back.

Comment: I get this error when using title in my orderby parameter value. "Invalid value for orderby parameter: title Error 400". Any help

Comment: @zak, It looks like title is no longer an option for orderby (this answer was from 2015).  You may have to grab all the posts and then do your sort in a callback.